# How to check if a symbolic link refers to a directory

Tags: c

I am currently recoding the "ls" command to learn. However, when I browse files: I may have an error when I try to open the "folder" of the path pointed by the symbolic link. Because it's not a directory (I thought all symbolic links pointed to folders).

How can I check if it points to a directory? (I watch the manuals, stat, dir ..)

Comment: Use [realpath(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) to get the "canonicalized absolute pathname" (ie. the element where the symlink points to), then do `stat` on it and use `S_ISDIR` to check if it's a directory.

Comment: Use `lstat()` versus `stat()` to get the properties of either the link or the thing the link points to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought all symbolic links pointed to folders

Nope.  A symbolic link is an indirect reference to another path.  That other path can refer to any kind of file that can be represented in any mounted file system, or to no file at all (i.e. it can be a broken link).

> How to check that it points to a directory?

You mention the `stat()` function, but for reimplementing `ls` you should mostly be using `lstat()`, instead.  The difference is that when the specified path refers to a symbolic link, `stat` returns information about the link's target path, whereas `lstat` returns information about the link itself (including information about the file type, from which you can tell that it *is* a link).

In the event that you encounter a symbolic link, you can simply check the same path again with `stat()` to find out what kind of file it points to.  `stat()` will recursively resolve symbolic links to discover the information for the ultimate target, which will be a symbolic link only if it is a broken one.  Any way around, you don't need to distinguish between a broken link and any other form of non-directory for your particular purpose.

Comment: Note that `stat` recursively follows links -- so using (just) it, you'll only ever get a return values with type S_IFLNK (symbolic link) for a broken link -- if it's not broken, you'll get the info of the target.  So realpath doesn't really gain you anything except a race condition if the file/link changes between the calls...

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisDodd, I clearly had a misunderstanding there.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, and here is my solution:

```
bool IsDir(const char *path)
{
    std::string tmp = path;
    tmp += '/';
    struct stat statbuf;
    return (lstat(tmp.c_str(), &statbuf) >= 0) && S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}
```

the key is the tail `/` in the path

however, I have no idea whether it's portable